# typescript tsc not working in windows 10 after npm i -g typescript

Tags: typescript

good Lord! I've installed typescript this way:

```
npm install -g typescript
```

and after that I am fallowing the tutorial trying to do

```
tsc --version
```

and then an error explodes:is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file etc etc

I am using windows 10, I added the path , I restarted the computer, etc

nothing happends

Please Help!!

thanks in advance hehe

Comment: if you look in the folder `%AppData%\npm\node_modules` do you see the typescript folder? in the folder `%AppData%\npm` do you see the tsc files?

Comment: Typescript yes tsc don t

Comment: That's strange. What version of npm are you using? Could you try doing a `npm install -g typescript --verbose` and add the output to your question

Comment: npm -v: 7.11.2 and in the %AppData%\npm\node_module what I see now is ts-node, besides typescript

Answer (score -1):

I just install ts-node

```
npm i -g ts-node
```

and now I can put

```
tsc --version
```

obtaining :

```
Version 4.2.4
```

Comment: `ts-node` is not the same as `typescript` library, even though it uses typescript underlyingly.

Comment: in which part I said the above...? tsc error come in hand of me fallowing a tutorial for learnig typescript, which tells me that after installing typescript globally : npm install -g typescript I can use this command: tsc --version...and all is fine, and it didn t. so after reading a while no solution fix my problem but npm i -g ts-node...is just a question with a final answer...hope saves someones' time